# MySQL query returns two array items, why?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this query, on two tables, and in first table, table **tblhosting** two condition must be met,  *WHERE tblhosting.server = tblservers.id AND tblhosting.domain = 'provided domain'*. "**provided domain** is unique and here is complete query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT hostname FROM tblhosting, tblservers WHERE tblhosting.server = tblservers.id AND tblhosting.domain = 'developer.infonet.hr'");
```

Query return correct result set, but two times, here is also var_dump output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "lin-b15.infonet.hr"
  ["hostname"]=>
  string(18) "lin-b15.infonet.hr"
}
```

Why is returning two same results, correct output is one, because domain is unique, is this because result is generate with mysq_fetch_array, so it is returning both associative array, and normal indexed array?

Comment: Thats alright you need to use the `index` name `hostname` while accessing the value.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean with index name hostname? Hostname isn't index but is unique record in table.

Comment: index means index of array like `[0]` and `hostname` means `["hostname"]` . You can use as $result['0'] or $result['hostname'].

Answer (score 1):

use

`mysql_fetch_row()` to Get a result row as an enumerated array

or

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` to Fetch a result row as an associative array

For Multiple record use it in while condition..

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I am confused because I been thinking that query returns two rows.